# jQuery can't access element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get access to an element via the console in firebug. For some reason jQuery can't find this element.

**Markup**

```
 <input type="text" id="when" readonly=""/>
```

**Console**

```
>>> document.getElementById('when')
<input id="when" type="text" readonly="">
>>> $('#when')
jQuery()
>>> jQuery('#when')
jQuery()
```

How is this possible? Why can't I access an element that I know is 100% in the page via the conole?

Comment: are you sure that you have added jquery library??

Comment: Please see here: http://m.sexdiaries.co.uk/#sex I didn't really want to post the url , but here goes :) Also rather than bickering and not helping me, care to explain why this is not working?

Comment: Yeah, I'm at work so I'm not clicking that link. Can you post a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thanks for the reply, of course jQuery has been added. How else could `$('#when')` return then jQuery object? `jQuery()`

Comment: ye makes sense @Andy Although It is safe for work (it contains the words 'wank' and 'sex'), I understand and its a very complex phonegap require application that I can't drop into fiddle :(

Comment: Just post the relevant code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Are you using [document-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). As its give correct out put in console

Comment: @Satpal I certainly am, no other elements other than this $('#when') is giving me problems. I am loading it through a complex JTS MVC method.

Comment: On a serious note though, does anybody have any clue why I can't access this element through the console? This is like nothing I've seen before.

Answer (score 2):

Very unhelpful comments, I'm not going to close the question to get the +score as somebody else might find this useful.

But I had no idea that you could turn off an element from being `discoverable`. The element is still in the document of course. But the `attr` `readonly` stops jQuery having access to it.

```
$('#when').data('turnoffelement', $('#when').prop('readonly')).prop('readonly', true);
```

Crazy times we live in.

Comment: What version of jQuery is this? I've just tried it on here by setting an input to `readonly`, and that seems to have no effect on whether it is "discoverable" or not.

Comment: did you also set the data? Without this it still functions as normal.  I'm using version 2.0.3. If you navigate to the url given and run that command in the console and then try to access `$('when') You'll see jquery can no longer access it, but you can retrieve it via `getElementById`

Comment: Absolutely cannot repro, sorry. Both `$('#when')` and `document.getElementById('when')` return null for me.